# Gridview does not display fully and has blank objects at the beginning

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, gridview

Trying to make a gridview but running into a few issues. The gridview does not display clearly and I have to scroll inside its layout even though there is space in the screen remaining. It also shows empty items inside it.
Here is a pic of what it looks like:
[App image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzbRd.jpg)

I dont get why there are these empty objects before the actual images pop up. Here is my code:

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/places"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="20dp"/>

    <GridView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:numColumns="3"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.placesofinterest;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.media.ThumbnailUtils;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;

import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static android.provider.Contacts.SettingsColumns.KEY;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    GridView gridView;
    GridAdapter gridAdapter;
    private final int THUMBNAIL_SIZE = 250;
    ArrayList<Bitmap> img = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    private String thumbURL[] = {"http://192.168.0.105/places/amsterdam_thumb.png",
            "http://192.168.0.105/places/bali_thumb.png", "http://192.168.0.105/places/dubai_thumb.png",
            "http://192.168.0.105/places/germany_thumb.png", "http://192.168.0.105/places/cambodia_thumb.png",
            "http://192.168.0.105/places/ireland_thumb.png", "http://192.168.0.105/places/japan_thumb.png",
            "http://192.168.0.105/places/prague_thumb.png", "http://192.168.0.105/places/sweden_thumb.png"};
    private String fullURL[] = {"http://192.168.0.105/places/amsterdam.png",
            "http://192.168.0.105/places/bali.png", "http://192.168.0.105/places/dubai.png",
            "http://192.168.0.105/places/germany.png", "http://192.168.0.105/places/cambodia.png",
            "http://192.168.0.105/places/ireland.png", "http://192.168.0.105/places/japan.png",
            "http://192.168.0.105/places/prague.png", "http://192.168.0.105/places/sweden.png"};
    private String location[] = {"Amsterdam", "Bali", "Dubai", "Germany", "Cambodia", "Ireland",
            "Japan", "Prague", "Sweden"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        for(int i = 0; i < fullURL.length; i++) {
            LoadingImages(fullURL[i]);
        }
    }

    private void LoadingImages(String s) {
        ImageLoader imageLoader = MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getImageLoader();
        imageLoader.get(s, new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {
                Bitmap image = response.getBitmap();
                Bitmap thumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(image, THUMBNAIL_SIZE, THUMBNAIL_SIZE);
                img.add(thumbnail);

                gridView = findViewById(R.id.grid);

                gridAdapter = new GridAdapter(MainActivity.this, img);
                gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);

                gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("error", error.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

GridAdapter.java:

```
package com.example.placesofinterest;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<Bitmap> img;

    public GridAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Bitmap> img){
        this.context = c;
        this.img = img;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return img.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return img.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.places_layout, null);
            MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(myViewHolder);
        }
        MyViewHolder myViewHolder = (MyViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        myViewHolder.img.setImageBitmap(img.get(position));

        return convertView;
    }

    public class MyViewHolder {
        public ImageView img;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            img = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        }
    }
}
```

places_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/wish" />
</LinearLayout>
```

MySingleton.java:

```
package com.example.placesofinterest;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.util.LruCache;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

public class MySingleton {
    private static MySingleton instance;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private static Context context;

    private MySingleton(Context context){
        this.context = context;
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(requestQueue, new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
            private final LruCache<String, Bitmap> cache = new LruCache<>(6);
            @Override
            public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                Bitmap bmp = cache.get(url);
                if (bmp == null) {
                    System.out.println("Not in cache");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("In cache");
                }

                return bmp;
            }

            @Override
            public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                System.out.println("Put in cache");
                cache.put(url, bitmap);
            }
        });
    }

    public static synchronized MySingleton getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new MySingleton(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        return imageLoader;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing LinearLayout for ScrollView. for example:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
<LinearLayout> ...
</ScrollView>
```